# Realm Object Server: The server is not available

Tags: realm

I'm new in using Realm Studio with Ubuntu. When I connect realm object server in web "localhost:9080" I was successfully connected, but when I tried to connect using realm object server via realm studio it always shows the server is not available and it's always trying to check the availability. 
What could be the problem for this?[See attach image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2mO6.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have deployed ROS 1.x which is not compatible with Studio. You can follow this tutorial to get up and running with 2.x: https://docs.realm.io/platform/getting-started